# Windows Library description number

Tags: windows, dll-injection

Windows Libraries that engage in Library Hijacking, typically have a number in their library description field. What is this field? How does Windows Process it and is there a mapping of int32-like values to DLL that Microsoft published?

For eg: `-34575` is the alternative name for `shell32.dll` (see the example below:)

````
<libraryDescription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2009/library">
  <name>@shell32.dll,-34575</name>
...
</libraryDescription>```
````

Comment: can you elaborate a little further? the `<name>@shell32.dll,-34575</name>` tag simply indicates that the value of this xml element is a resource id that resides in the resource file associated with `shell32.dll`, i.e. `shell32.dll.mui`. `-34575` resolves to "Documents".